# PHP Appending year the select menu

Tags: php

I have this custom function in place, It will get the current year from the date function in php. When next year will come I want to append next year with previous year.

Example:
Current Year is "2013"
Next year will be "2014"
When year will come, It should dynamically add 2014 to drop-down list.

```
<select>
<option>2014</option>
<option>2013</option>
</select>

function ec_year(){
    $year = date("Y");
}
```

Anyone any help please.

Comment: please explain more so that we can help..and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
$start_year = '2013';
$current_year = date("Y");
echo '<select>';
for ($i=$start_year; $i <= $current_year; $i++) { 
    echo '<option>' . $i .'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this give the end year as you like ...it will automatically work on present year

```
<select>
<?php for($i=date(Y);$i>=endyear);$i--){

<option><?php echo $i;?></option>

 <?php }?></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select>
    <option><?php print(Date("Y") + 1); ?></option>
    <option><?php print(Date("Y")); ?></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
echo date('Y')+1; #will give current year + 1
```